# How do I copy or edit a cell of attribute table and paste in text file?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, vba, copy

I'm new in VBA. I want to copy one cell or optional cell in attribute table and paste in a text file.

I'm using ArcGis 10.1.

Comment: Which GIS or file format do you use?

Answer (score 1):

This might be for what you are looking:

[image]

You need to right click on the attribute table, on the little gray squares all the way to the left. The output will be all the fields (including names), tab delimited.